# java send firmware thru telnet

Tags: java, android, networking, telnet

Hallo i an trying to send Firmware file to modem board thru telnet.
Here is my code:

```
    Socket s = null;
    try {
                SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(addr), 23);
                s = new Socket();
                s.connect(socketAddress, 1000);

        InputStream inputStream = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write( (login + "\n") .getBytes());

        Thread.sleep(300);

        outputStream.write( (password + "\n") .getBytes());

        Thread.sleep(300);

                    outputStream.write(("swupdate" + "\n").getBytes());
                     Thread.sleep(300);                   

                      // Open the file that is the first
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path_frm_vdsl);
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Print the content on the console
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } else {
                //System.out.println(line);
                outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
                Log.v("---", line.getBytes() + "" + consumeInput(500, inputStream));
                //Log.v("Update_Modem","Updated " + consumeInput(500, inputStream));
                //outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
```

It simply logs in sends swupdate command and dumps firmware file to output. After first line of input i am having java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
And i can not read all file at once, not enough memory exception. (3Mb)

Comment: What is the content of the firmware? You are reading it "line by line" which is not applicable if the content is not text. Also, you throw away every other line since you do br.readLine twice.

Comment: Firmware is binary file. Do you know better method to read the file in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your receiving end wants the firmware, plain binary, hex encoded, base64 encoded?

Anyway, here is how you would send it in plain binary

```
Socket s = null;
try {
    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(addr), 23);
    s = new Socket();
    s.connect(socketAddress, 1000);

    InputStream inputStream = s.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();

    outputStream.write((login + "\n").getBytes());

    Thread.sleep(300);

    outputStream.write((password + "\n").getBytes());

    Thread.sleep(300);

    outputStream.write(("swupdate" + "\n").getBytes());
    Thread.sleep(300);

    // Open the file that is the first
    // command line parameter
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path_frm_vdsl);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int fillSize;

    // Read File chunk by chunk
    while ((fillSize = fstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, fillSize);
    }
    outputStream.close();
} finally {
    s.close();
}
```

So, read the file in chunks until there is no more data (read returns -1) and write the chunk (read returns how much was actually read).

Answer (score 2):

You know telnet uses in-channel signalling?  the data stream contains escaped command instructions.  When you open a telnet connection, a whole slew of initial commands are passed back and forth, as the server and client determine each others capabilities and preferences.

You may well find your byte stream is corrupted, if you just take whatever you get turning up at the server.  You will need to honour the telnet protocol, e.g. properly understand the byte stream you're receiving.

Answer (score 1):

The line terminator in the Telnet protcol is \r\n.

But why would you want to read the whole file into memory? And why all the sleeps? And why are you skipping every second line? And what is consumeInput()?

Just read and write *bytes.*